# disambiguate this tag, check its [pulse]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I just finished an analysis of the [pulse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pulse) tag and found a huge amount of variation. All of the current questions fall into one of these categories (posted in the newly created tag wiki):

**Software**

- RSS news reader app for Android, iOS and HTML5 browsers, released around 2010.
- JunOS Pulse, the SSL VPN client
- [Pulse CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_CMS), content management for small web sites
- The [Zutubi Pulse](http://zutubi.com/) continuous integration server
- Various Salesforce.com plugins ([examples](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=salesforce%20pulse))
- C# `Monitor.Pulse` (discouraged, too granular)
- The Python function `wxGauge.Pulse` (discouraged, too granular)

**Concepts**

- an [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation) (use that tag instead)
- an animation type defined by AnimationExtender (ASP.NET AJAX). use [animationextender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animationextender)
- human pulse sensors (eg. Arduino integration)
- for analog engineers, a [pulse wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave) is a bar graph created from 1-D vector input data. [pulse generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_generator) can be used to generate this type of signal. pulse waveforms are commonly used in synthesizer programming.
- Radio control pulse position modulation encoding (PPM), pulse code modulation (PCM), pulse width modulation (PWM). try [remote-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) or [modulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulation) instead

Comment: Guess I am looking for an answer with a better option than creating 7 new tags for the non-discouraged, non-existing tag...